# react/redux/sagas - how to chain actions based on existing store data?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am trying to fire actions inside of a saga based on if the state contains data or not.

Since I already have sagas for getting the data from books/games, I want to reuse that functionality. And I only want to fire those if the store is empty of that data.

This is my code so far...

```
function* getAllSaga(action) {
    try {

        let books = yield select(Selectors.books);
        let games = yield select(Selectors.games);

        if(!books.length || !games.length){
            yield put({ type: 'GET_BOOKS' });
            yield put({ type: 'GET_GAMES' });
        }

        books = yield select(Selectors.books);
        games = yield select(Selectors.games);

        const concated = books.concat(games);

        yield put({ type: 'GET_ALL_SUCCEEDED', all: concated });

    } catch (err) {
        yield put({ type: 'GET_ALL_FAILED', message: err.message });
    }
}
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`put`s are non blocking so you need to modify your code so that it waits for the new data like so:

```
function* getAllSaga(action) {
    try {

        let books = yield select(Selectors.books);
        let games = yield select(Selectors.games);

        if(!books.length || !games.length){
            yield put({ type: 'GET_BOOKS' });
            yield put({ type: 'GET_GAMES' });
            yield all([
                take('GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED'),
                take('GET_GAMES_SUCCEEDED')
            ])
            books = yield select(Selectors.books);
            games = yield select(Selectors.games);
        }

        const concated = books.concat(games);

        yield put({ type: 'GET_ALL_SUCCEEDED', all: concated });

    } catch (err) {
        yield put({ type: 'GET_ALL_FAILED', message: err.message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is `take('BOOKS_LOADED')`? Where does that come from?

Comment: Well, you said `I already have sagas for getting the data from books/games`. I assume those are run when you dispatch GET_BOOKS/GET_GAMES actions. Once the fetch logic in those sagas is finished you are storing the returned data to state using some actions. I called them BOOKS_LOADED/GAMES_LOADED. But use whatever name you use instead.

Comment: I have `GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED`, but that does not do anything, it is the `GET_BOOKS` that actually gets the books... if I use `take('GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED')` nothing happens, it does not seem to get passed the `yield all([...])` at all.

Comment: I can see that `GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED` is fired in the logger.

Comment: I figured it out... `take('GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED')` was not working because it was not in the correct order. The following worked:
`            yield all([
                yield put({ type: 'GET_GAMES' }),
                yield take('GET_GAMES_SUCCEEDED'),
                yield put({ type: 'GET_BOOKS' }),
                yield take('GET_BOOKS_SUCCEEDED'),
            ])
`

Comment: My code should work as long as the loading sagas are asynchronous. The all effect should yield on all effects in the array so the yields in the array shouldn't be necessary.